# trying to install apache httpd.2.4.51 ,while doing compile getting error like mk:75: all recursive error1,so pls suggest

Tags: apache2, compiling

```
Making all in srclib
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/software/httpd-2.4.51/srclib'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/software/httpd-2.4.51/srclib'
Making all in os
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/software/httpd-2.4.51/os'
Making all in unix
make[2]: Entering directory '/root/software/httpd-2.4.51/os/unix'
make[3]: Entering directory '/root/software/httpd-2.4.51/os/unix'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'local-all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/root/software/httpd-2.4.51/os/unix'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/software/httpd-2.4.51/os/unix'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/software/httpd-2.4.51/os'
Making all in server
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/software/httpd-2.4.51/server'
Making all in mpm
make[2]: Entering directory '/root/software/httpd-2.4.51/server/mpm'
Making all in event
make[3]: Entering directory '/root/software/httpd-2.4.51/server/mpm/event'
make[4]: Entering directory '/root/software/httpd-2.4.51/server/mpm/event'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'local-all'.
make[4]: Leaving directory '/root/software/httpd-2.4.51/server/mpm/event'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/root/software/httpd-2.4.51/server/mpm/event'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/software/httpd-2.4.51/server/mpm'
make[2]: Entering directory '/root/software/httpd-2.4.51/server'
bison -pap_expr_yy --defines=/root/software/httpd-2.4.51/server/util_expr_parse.h \
    -o /root/software/httpd-2.4.51/server/util_expr_parse.c /root/software/httpd-2.4.51/server/util_expr_parse.y
/bin/bash: bison: command not found
make[2]: *** [Makefile:98: util_expr_scan.c] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/software/httpd-2.4.51/server'
make[1]: *** [/root/software/httpd-2.4.51/build/rules.mk:75: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/software/httpd-2.4.51/server'
make: *** [/root/software/httpd-2.4.51/build/rules.mk:75: all-recursive] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You lack `bison`:

```
/bin/bash: bison: command not found
```

from your log.

`sudo apt install bison` should take care of this.

## The output is there for a reason.

The output tells you *what* went on, and what went wrong. Actually reading it will very often give you clear clues on where to start. In this case the error message was essentially in clear english: *bison: command not found*

As a sidenote, why do you need to compile Apache from source? That makes maintaining it a much bigger job. Installing from repos is particularly useful when it comes to software that require frequent security updates.